# chart js don't center pie chart correctrly

Tags: canvas, chart.js

As you can see in image it is not centered correctrly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvbvF.png)

the only options for chart is

```
options: any = {
    cutout: '94%',
    
  };
```

I wont pie chart inside canvas to be renrede from the center in this caes it would be x-200 y-200

Answer (score 0):

it appeared that it is because of legend margins. this video helped
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87rnMzENg3U
just changed height to 0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).